# Python to update JSON file

Tags: python, json

After googling around and checking some other posts I still haven't found a solution for my issue.

Let me quickly explain what I'm after:

I've got a JSON configuration file with the following syntax:

```
    [
        {
                "name": "Name 1",
                "provider": "Provider 1",
                "url": "/1",
                "source": "URL"
        },
        {
                "name": "Name 2",
                "provider": "Provider 2",
                "url": "/1",
                "source": "URL 2"
        }

]
```

My issue is the key source changes and I've got a script generating these however I'm not able to find a way to update them automatically ideally I would need to tell my python script to look out for "Provider 1" and then update with the new URL for Provider 1 but my JSON format does not include individual keys and hence I need to search via Provider name and update the source.

Hope this makes sense any help appreciated.

Comment: So what's the question exactly ? How to look in the Json for dictionaries where `"provider"`equals `"Provider 1"` ?

Comment: Correct look at let say  "provider": "Provider 1" then update the source URL below. There will be about 18 different providers with different names where I need to update the URL every X hours.

Comment: may a provider appear different times ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something similar to below;

```
    myList = [
            {
                    "name": "Name 1",
                    "provider": "Provider 1",
                    "url": "/1",
                    "source": "URL"
            },
            {
                    "name": "Name 2",
                    "provider": "Provider 2",
                    "url": "/1",
                    "source": "URL 2"
            }

    ]

    def insertOrUpdate(updatedObj):
            existing = [x for x in myList if x['provider'] == updatedObj['provider']]
            if len(existing) == 1:
                    existing[0]['url'] = updatedObj['url']
            else:
                    myList.append(updatedObj)

    insertOrUpdate({"name": "Name 1", "provider": "Provider 1", "url": "updated Url", "source": "URL"})
    insertOrUpdate({"name": "Name X", "provider": "Provider X", "url": "new Url", "source": "URL"})
```

Comment: @Nils_92 Use this function coupled with `crontab` to update your list automatically at a given time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `test.json` is your json file containing the text you inserted in the question, you can do the following

```
import json
with open('test.json') as my_file:
    json_content = json.load(my_file)
for ele in json_content:
    print(ele)
```

{'name': 'Name 1', 'provider': 'Provider 1', 'source': 'URL', 'url': '/1'}

{'name': 'Name 2', 'provider': 'Provider 2', 'source': 'URL 2', 'url': '/1'}

```
new_url = 'something. Define it as you want.'
for ele in json_content:
    if ele['provider']=='Provider 1':
        ele['url']=new_url
for ele in json_content:
    print(ele)
for ele in json_content:

print(ele)
```

{'name': 'Name 1', 'provider': 'Provider 1', 'source': 'URL', 'url': 'something. Define it as you want.'}
{'name': 'Name 2', 'provider': 'Provider 2', 'source': 'URL 2', 'url': '/1'}

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much both answers do work I just need to adapt some more code in order to make it ready as @MMF suggested the script should then run via cron.

Thanks a lot for your help guys!!